# In SSIS, how to loop through the XML inside a specific element using XPATH in a Foreach NodeList Enumerator

Tags: xml, xpath, foreach, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to loop through the XML elements of an XML input file in SSIS.
For this I am trying to use a 'Foreach Loop Container' with a Foreach Loop Container. Inside the ForEach Loop Container, I'd like to get the xml code as a String Variable.

I am fairly new to SSIS, and have been browsing the web for quite some time, yet could not get it right..

Input file example;
[image: input file ex.]
(Note that there are some cyrillic symbols in there, which may cause issues. However, when I take out the cyrillic symbols, the same error message shows).

I am trying to loop through the  nodes.

This is the package I have created so far;

[image]

Below the ForEach loop;
I have a variable called 'CurrencyRate' which is a String mapped there.
[image: ForEach loop]

And the XML Task inside the loop. This is just for testing purposes, it should write the last node element to that output file, with tags and values.

[image: XML Task]

However, if I run the code as it is, I get the below error message, even though I do not see any NULL values in my data. And I have no idea where the japanese(?) symbol comes from..;
[image: error]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! SSIS looks like a powerful tool and I would love to be able to be able to wield it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the Foreach NodeList Enumerator I am now using the Foreach From Variable Enumerator.

This is the entire package;

[image: new package]

Using following variables;

[image: variables]

With below script in the first Script Task 'CurrencyRates from XML to Array';
This code will get the XML and put each node as an object in an array. This array is then passed to an object variable.

```
        public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        System.Collections.ArrayList arr = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load((String)Dts.Variables["User::file_path"].Value + Dts.Variables["User::file_name"].Value);
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//CurrencyRate"); // You can also use XPath here
        foreach (XmlNode CurrencyRate in nodes)
        {
            arr.Add((String)CurrencyRate.InnerXml);
        }


        Dts.Variables["User::CurrencyRates"].Value = arr;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

This object variable is then looped using the Foreach From Variable Enumerator, mapping the nodes to an object variable 'CurrencyRate_Item'.
In the loop, this item is moved in a String variable, which we can then use for our needs.

Comment: Kudos for taking the time to post  detailed solution. You made the internet a little smarter today.